# Поиск текста между "(" и ")" в строке PHP

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения, поиск, замена

Мне необходимо в PHP, при помощи регулярки вытащить из строки все элементы текста, заключённые в скобки, для  их дальнейшей обработки, пример строки:
`(Ширина)*(Длина)+(Пользовательская константа)`
Это мне нужно, чтобы в итоге заменить их на имена переменных в Js и получить строку вида:
`Width*Height+User_constant`
Данные для перевода - укажу в массиве, но не знаю как сделать саму замену. Если можете, то помогите хоть с регуляркой(поиск этого самого текста между скобками) и выведением результата в массив

Comment: Между шириной и длиной знак "x"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *вытащить из строки все элементы текста, заключённые в скобки*

Дак *preg_match_all()* используйте:

```
$str = '(Ширина)*(Длина)+(Пользовательская константа)';

$pattern = '~\(\K.+?(?=\))~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

---

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Ширина' (length=12)
      1 => string 'Длина' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Пользовательская константа' (length=51)
```

Comment: Домой приду, попробую, отпишусь

Comment: @DaniilPetrenko можете и в [песочнице](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3865c8b14bc4e3344508841a21b4f77b5259004b) протестировать.

Answer (score 1):

Я решил в данном случае использовать разделитель "|", т.к. скобки могут использоваться многоуровненно вроде ((x)+(y))/(z), теперь я отредактировал регулярное выражение
    `~\(\K.+?(?=\))~`
и привел его к виду:
    `~\|\K.+?(?=\|)~`
Теперь при запросе: 
|Ширина двери|/|Цена бревна ев|-|Длина двери|
Я получаю:

````
[0]=> array(5){
[0]=> string(23) "Ширина двери" 
[1]=> string(1) "/" 
[2]=> string(26) "Цена бревна ев" 
[3]=> string(1) "-" 
[4]=> string(21) "Длина двери" } 
}```
````

Comment: Это поможет мне также при создании алгоритма-переводчика в JS выражение